# Conda ERROR _sysconfigdata_x86_64_conda_linux_gnu

Tags: python, installation, pip, conda, anaconda3

I have one error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sysconfigdata_x86_64_conda_linux_gnu'
Using comand: pip3 install --editable ./BindingSitesFromFragments

Comment: File "/opt/app/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/sysconfig.py", line 430, in _init_posix
    _temp = __import__(name, globals(), locals(), ['build_time_vars'], 0)

Comment: Please include the steps (commands) that lead to the error (edit the question). An error alone is not sufficient to diagnose an issue.

Comment: `conda install -c anaconda python=3.8.12`, just upgrading the python solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 31):

I had this problem after installing anaconda (w/ python3.8.8) on Ubuntu 20.04 on an aws ec2 instance.

Here is my error message:

```
"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sysconfigdata_x86_64_conda_linux_gnu'"
```

After a search

```
sudo find / -name _sysconfigdata_x86_64*`
```

and found the file

```
/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/_sysconfigdata_x86_64_conda_cos6_linux_gnu.py
```

Copying this file to the name of the missing file solved my problem

```
cd ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8
cp _sysconfigdata_x86_64_conda_cos6_linux_gnu.py _sysconfigdata_x86_64_conda_linux_gnu.py
```

Comment: I had the same issue after updating conda with python3.8.8, your fix worked like a charm, thank you!

Comment: Same here, for me the file was looking for _sysconfigdata_x86_64_conda_cos7_linux_gnu.py but the find only found  _sysconfigdata_x86_64_conda_cos6_linux_gnu.py so I just copied it to the new name and so far it works. Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I solved it installing `python=3.9`, but at first it seemed that the problem was still there, but I deactivated the environment, activated again and the problem was gone. I guess that might work with your python version as well if you install it, deactivate and reactivate the conda environment.

Answer (score -1):

works however, it will throw an another error, Downgrade the pandas to 0.20.3 or 1.4.1 worked for me
#--------------------------------
from pandas.util._exceptions import find_stack_level
ImportError: cannot import name 'find_stack_level' from 'pandas.util._exceptions' (/home/pontis/anaconda3/envs/stats1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/util/_exceptions.py)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).